# Payoff matrix with a specific form

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

I am very stuck on this question:

Suppose that $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ is a $m \times n$ real matrix, and all components of $A$, $b$ and $c$ are positive. Consider the two-person zero-sum game in which each player has $m+n+1$ pure strategies and the payoff matrix is
\begin{equation}  M= \Bigg( \begin{array}{c:c} 0 & A& -b \\ \hdashline
-A^{T} & 0 & c  \\ \hdashline b^{T} & -c^{T} & 0 \end{array} \Bigg). \end{equation}

There are $3$ parts:

$1.$  Find the equilibrium payoff for player 1 (row player).

$2.$ If both players have the same optimal mixed strategy in the game being 
\begin{equation}
 \pi^{T} = (p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m, q_1, \ldots, q_n, r),
\end{equation}
prove that $r \neq 0$.

$3.$ Explain how to find from $\pi$ an optimal solution to the linear program
\begin{equation}
 \{ \text{ maximize } c^{T} y \, : \, Ay \leq b, y\geq 0\}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Did you solve 2?

Comment: still not yet...

Comment: @Stefanos I don't really understand your solution to the 3rd part. You argue that using strong duality suffices, but I don't know what is the optimal solution of the dual. Is p the optimal solution? Also, I don't know the reason for proving that $b^{T} p = c^{T} q$. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You need to use that $π^T$ gives you the value against any strategy of player II. This means that $π^T$ times the first column of M equals the value equals 0, $π^T$ times the second column of M equals the value equals 0, $π^T$ times the second column of M equals the value equals 0. This will give you 3 equations. Now, strong duality says that if q is feasible for the primal and p is feasible for the dual and the give the same value for the respective objecive function then these vectors are optimal solutions and the value they yield is the optimal solution. But first divide with r to make

Comment: them feasible. You need to make some effort to study these things from your textbook.

Comment: @Stefanos  OK, thanks, I was only taught in class about the complementary slackness conditions. Didn't really realise that same objective value of primal feasible solns and dual feasible solns implies optimality. Also, one more question: you seem to be using (a lot) the fact that ${\pi}^{T} M = \mathbf{0}$, but all we know is, by definition, ${\pi}^{T} M \pi = 0$, since $\pi$ is not necessarily a zero vector.

Comment: See my edit. In the end I completely did your homework. It is fine with me this time, but it will not get you very far. I will be glad to see next time that you did more effort by yourself! Good luck with your course and see you again.

Comment: @Stefanos Thanks a lot. (I am new to this area of maths.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For 1.** Use the following

> **Proposition 3.4** *If the payoff matrix for a two-player zero-sum game is skew-symmetric,
> i.e. $M^T$ = −M, then the value of the game is $0$ and the optimal mixed strategies for both
> players are the same. The game is then said to be symmetric.*

that you can find in this [link](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpersonal.maths.surrey.ac.uk%2Fst%2FA.Skeldon%2FModules%2FMAT3002%2FM.Econ-Ch3%2C4.pdf&ei=OplrVPLaKY7VasvOgNgK&usg=AFQjCNFcUbxPmGgqIfhM0yU4IeLEj-tr3Q&bvm=bv.79908130,d.d2s) or in any textbook.

**For 2**. Since $π$ is optimal and the game is $0$ sum we know that $π$ *guarantees* the value of the game (i.e. $0$) for player I against any strategy of player II (we will use also in part 3. below). Assume know that $r=0$, then $π$ against the first strategy of player II yields a payoff $$π^TMe_1=p^T0+q^T\left(-A^T_{\cdot 1}\right)+0\cdot c_1=-q^TA_{\cdot 1}$$ where with $A^T_{\cdot 1}$ we denote the first column of the matrix $A^T$. Now this payoff is negative since all the elements of $-A$ are negative unless $q$ is the zero vector. But if $q$ is the zero vector then the payoff of $π$ against the last strategy of Player II is equal to $$π^ΤΜe_{m+n+1}=-p^Tb+0<0$$ which is a contradiction. So $r>0$. Similarly we can show more, i.e. that $p,q$ are not the zero vectors.

**For 3.** Use that $π$ guarantees to Player I his security level against any strategy of Player II, i.e. that $π^ΤΜe_j\ge 0$ for every $j=1,2,\ldots, m+n+1$. This gives the set of inequalities $$\begin{cases}-q^TA^T+rb^T\ge0\\p^TA-rc^T\ge0\\-p^Tb+q^Tc\ge0\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\dfrac{q^T}{r}A^T\le b^T\\\dfrac{p^T}{r}A\ge c^T\\\dfrac{p^T}{r}b\le \dfrac{q^T}{r}c\end{cases}$$ The first inequality gives you that the vector $\dfrac{q^T}{r}$ is primal feasible, the second inequality that the vector $\dfrac{p^T}{r}$ is dual feasible and the third that the value of the objective function of the primal LP for the primal feasible vector $\dfrac{q^T}{r}$ is greater or equal than the value of the objective function of the dual LP for the dual feasible vector $\dfrac{p^T}{r}$. Due to strong duality (actually weak duality suffices) this yields optimality of the solutions.